# Chess, go and rubik's cube through mathematics

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I am seeking some good and pleasant references for people who are mathematicians but most of all deeply interested in games of all types, mainly combinatorial games (go, chess, rubik's cube, even Candy crush !).

Is there any good references interpreting this king of game through mathematics, either historical or mainly mathematical?

Comment: Take a look at Berlekamp's [books](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=dp_byline_sr_book_1?ie=UTF8&text=Elwyn+Berlekamp&search-alias=books&field-author=Elwyn+Berlekamp&sort=relevancerank).

Comment: The whole field of combinatorial game theory was pretty much developed with Go (mainly the end game) in mind. Not sure I would call Rubik's cube a game (it is certainly not a combinatorial game), but there are clear applications of group theory.

Comment: I suggest "Winning Ways for your Mathematical Plays". By Elwyn R. Berlekamp, John H. Conway and Richard K. Guy.

Comment: It's hard to draw the line between mathematics and games, especially when the game is go or checkers or chess. But Raymond Smullyan has a couple of books on chess that anyone who likes chess or math will enjoy. Instead of trying to figure out what to do next, Smullyan asks you to figure out how you got where you are now. For some reason I can't pin down these problems seem (to me) more like math than the game itself.